# How to handle external modules when writing unit tests for server-side Javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am unit testing a JS file that has a `require` that points to an external module. How do I handle the external module when running UT if it keeps on looking for that external module locally?

I already tried mocking a function from the script, but I do not think that is the proper way to test its components. What I really want is for my test file to point to the script file, and that script file will either skip the call for the `require` part that calls the external modules OR find a way to override or ignore that line so that I can start referencing the functions and components I need in the script file for unit testing.

**Deal.js**

```
var cordra = require('cordra');
var util = require('util');

exports.beforeSchemaValidation = beforeSchemaValidation;

function beforeSchemaValidation(deal, context) {
...
return deal;
}
```

**DealTest.js**

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
const beforeSchemaValidation = require('../rules/Deal').beforeSchemaValidation;

describe('Deal', function() {
  it('beforeSchemaValidation should return object', function() {
    let result = beforeSchemaValidation();
    assert.typeOf(result, Object);
  });
});
```

I want my test file to run through `../rules/Deal` without getting a thrown error of `Error: Cannot find module 'cordra'` and/or `'util'` so I can test the rest of its components.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in following way :

```
var cordra = require('cordra');
var util = require('util');

function beforeSchemaValidation(deal, context) {
...
return deal;
}

module.exports = {
beforeSchemaValidation: beforeSchemaValidation }
```